# Every Grothendieck topos can be built from localic topoi

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, locales

Theorem 2 in [these notes](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/278xnotes/Lecture16-Enumerations.pdf)[1] states that, roughly, that each Grothendieck topos can be built (using limits and colimits) from localic topoi. To what extent is that related to the [theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412504/an-extension-of-the-galois-theory-of-grothendieck) of Joyal and Tierney which states that each Grothendieck topos is equivalent to the topos of equivariant sheaves on a groupoid in the category of locales?

1. Jacob Lurie, 2018, lecture notes from Math 278X Categorical Logic, [https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/278x.html](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/278x.html), Lecture 16 *Enumerations*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The groupoid representation of Joyal and Tierney may be identified with the truncated simplicial diagram appearing in the statement of Theorem 2 of the Lurie notes mentioned in the question. That is, a groupoid object is precisely a diagram of the shape indicated in Theorem 2 satisfying some axioms, which are automatically satisfied by construction when one takes pseudopullbacks as indicated in the diagram. In Joyal and Tierney's theorem, the groupoid in localic toposes is precisely this groupoid: it has topos of objects $U$, topos of 1-cells $U \times_X U$, and so forth.

To elaborate a bit, the diagram displayed in Theorem 2, which looks like

$U \times_X U \times_X U ^\to_\to \to U \times_X U ^\to_\to U$

(implicitly there are also some maps going back in the reverse direction) is really just the first few stages of the [Cech nerve](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%C4%8Cech+nerve) of the map $U \to X$. The Cech nerve as a whole is indexed by the dual simplex category $\Delta^{op}$, and here we just have the part on the 3 smallest objects of $\Delta^{op}$, namely $[0], [1], [2]$. It may be more familiar that when you truncate all the way to just two objects $[0],[1]$, you get the maps $U \times_X U ^\to_\to U$ -- the kernel pair of the map $U \to X$, which is an equivalence relation. The higher analog of the fact that a kernel pair is always an equivalence relation is that the Cech nerve of a map is always a groupoid object -- $[0]$ corresponds to the objects of the groupoid, $[1]$ corresponds to the morphisms, $[2]$ corresponds to composable pairs of morphisms (*not* to 2-cells), and in general $[n]$ corresponds to composable $n$-tuples of morphisms.

You can more generally think of an internal category object (not just an internal groupoid object) in a category as a certain type of simplicial object, as described [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category#internal_nerve).

Comment: Thanks. I don't see any "truncated simplicial diagram", though. I also don't know what that is. :-)

Comment: "it has topos of objects U, topos of 1-cells U×XU, and so forth" this suggests there are 2-cells. but what do you mean by n-cells and why do we need 2-cells? we are not doing higher category theory here!

Comment: @user477332 : In general for a map $U \to X$ in a category, its Czech nerve is the simplicial complex whose $n$-th object is the $(n+1)$-folds fiber product $U \times_X U \times_X \dots \times_X U$. The object Tim is talking about corresponds to the first three objects of that complex. In this case you need $2$-cells to get the groupoids structure: the associativity of the groupoid multiplication is expressed as a certain equation between maps $U \times_X U \times_X U \to U $, which is part of the simplicial structure at level $2$.

Comment: Also, you *are* doing higher category here : you are working in the $2$-category of toposes, that's why you need to go one level higher in the simplicial complexe than you would normally do in a $1$-category.

Comment: @SimonHenry haha "Czech nerve" :)

Comment: There are many things that are unclear to me. Why is a localic groupoid the same as such a 2-truncated simplicial diagram in the 2-category of topoi? Why does the topos of equivarient sheaves of a localic groupoid coincide with the colimit of such a 2-truncated simplicial diagram? What do you mean by the statement that the axioms are automatically satisfied when one takes pseudopullbacks, and how do you prove that? How do you know that there are implicitly also some maps going back in the reverse direction? Lurie didn't write that.

Comment: "You can more generally think of an internal category object (not just an internal groupoid object) in a category as a certain type of simplicial object, as described here." Why? The nLab link you gave descibes an internal nerve construction. Are you claiming that this construction exhibits a bijection between internal categories in A and 2-truncated simplicial objects $S_\bullet$ in A satisfying the condition that each $\Lambda_1^2\to S_\bullet$ has a unique filler? (Is that what you mean by "a certain type of simplicial object" or am I missing a condition?)

Comment: I don't have 10 years of experience with higher categories - you have to make these claims precise if you want that I understand what you mean. :-) People often give nLab links but mostly I find them unhelpful because I have the feeling only experts can understand them. :-(

Comment: Also, nLab talks about internal categories in a *1-category*. But we are in a 2-category (the 2-category of topoi).

Comment: @SimonHenry Yes, we *are* doing higher category theory on the meta level, because we work with the 2-category of topoi. But I was referring to the fact Tim talked about "-cells" of that simplicial diagram. That's on another stage. But now I understand what he means by "-cells". But what do you mean by "that's why you need to go one level higher in the simplicial complexe than you would normally do in a 1-category"? Even if you talk about internal categories in a *1-categories* I think you need 2-cells to encode composition of you want to code the internal category as a simplicial object.

Comment: What's funny about "Czech nerve"? Seems like a misspelling?

Comment: @user477332. Not all (truncated or not) simplicial objects corresponds to a groupoids objects, but groupoids objects form a full subcategory of (truncated) simplicial objects they can be characterized by so called Segal conditions. WHat I said about being in a 2-category is because if you take the colimits of a simplicial objets in a 1-category the results only depends on the first two object, in a 2-category it depends on the first three objects (and more generally in an n-category it depends on the first (n+1)-objects.)

Comment: The fact that equivariant sheaves corresponds to the colimits of the simplicial diagram follows from two fact : 1) colimits of Grothendieck toposes are computed as (pseudo)-limits of the underlying categories (for the f^* functors). 2) The definition of an equivariant sheaves is exactly the spelled out version of what this pseudo-limits is for a 2-truncated simplicial object.... Oh And yes the "Czech nerve" was indeed just a typo, but that's kinda funny because Cech  is Czech, so I guess it is indeed a Czech nerve.

Comment: Fwiw, "Čech" is the Czech spelling and "Czech" is the Polish spelling.

Comment: @ZhenLin No, the Polish spelling is "Čech" too: https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduard_%C4%8Cech.

Comment: @SimonHenry Thanks for answering some of my questions.

Comment: @TimCampion There are still a lot of questions left ... I won't accept your answer until you give either rigorous proofs of all statements or precise references for all the claims, rather than an answer that just experts are able to understand using a lot of folklore knowledge that is not available to me.

Comment: @user477332 I sense some frustration. I think you're expecting a back-and-forth where we peel back the layers together, trying to identify exactly what you know and what you don't know in order to tailor an answer to your particular existing knowledge, like a teacher in office hours. MO is not ideally suited to such a process (it's not a chat platform) -- it's more like bumping into a colleague at tea and chatting for a few minutes. That said, several people have been explaining things, and I've lost track of what you're still confused about. If you can catch me up, I can try to help.

Comment: @user477332 i take that back. Rather, let me reassure you that it’s quite _normal_ for two mathematicians to realize partway through a conversation that they don’t share the same background knowledge. No need to get worked up over it. I’m having difficulty gauging where our common language does lie, though. So in order to help I do need it explained to me what is confusing at this point.

Comment: @TimCampion I see. My main questions are about making precise the things you sketched, because I don't have much experience in higher category theory (while you answer as an expert in higher category theory). I agree that the comment section might not be the best place for long discussions. So maybe I should just keep learning higher category theory and come back to this thread in a while to see whether I can prove the things myself! Let me say thank you (and also thanks to Simon Henry and Zhen Lin Low) - your answer(s) already gave me an idea of what's going on. :-)

Comment: @user477332 I was referring to the language/nationality.

Answer (score 12):

They are (it is?) the same theorem, but emphasising different aspects.

We can exploit the object classifier to get from the formulation in terms of (pseudo)colimits to the "elementary" formulation in terms of equivariant sheaves.
The point is that, for every Grothendieck topos $\mathcal{E}$, the functor $\textbf{Geom} (\mathcal{E}, [\textbf{Set}_\textrm{fin}, \textbf{Set}]) \to \mathcal{E}$ sending a geometric morphism $f : \mathcal{E} \to [\textbf{Set}_\textrm{fin}, \textbf{Set}]$ to the object $f^* A$ in $\mathcal{E}$, where $A : \textbf{Set}_\textrm{fin} \to \textbf{Set}$ is the inclusion, is fully faithful and essentially surjective on objects.
That is, $[\textbf{Set}_\textrm{fin}, \textbf{Set}]$ represents the contravariant forgetful 2-functor that sends a Grothendieck topos to its underlying category.
It immediately follows that (bi)colimits in the 2-category of Grothendieck toposes are (bi)limits of the underlying categories.
(It is awkward to keep using the 2- / bi- prefixes, so I will omit it from here onwards.)

So, for example, the initial Grothendieck topos is the terminal category, the coproduct of Grothendieck toposes is the product of the underlying categories, the pushout of Grothendieck toposes is the pullback of the underlying categories, etc.
What about the colimit of the diagram appearing in Lurie's formulation of the theorem?
Well, the underlying category is the limit of the diagram of the underlying categories, and because the forgetful functor is contravariant, the shape of the diagram is also dualised.
If you write out explicitly the universal property of the limit, you will find that it is an extremely terse way of writing something that looks like a groupoid action.

Indeed, suppose given categories $\mathcal{C}^0$, $\mathcal{C}^1$, and $\mathcal{C}^2$ and functors $d^0, d^1 : \mathcal{C}^0 \to \mathcal{C}^1$, $d^0, d^1, d^2 : \mathcal{C}^1 \to \mathcal{C}^2$, satisfying the cosimplicial identities (strictly, to preserve our sanity).
So we have a truncated cosimplicial object in $\textbf{Cat}$, and its limit is (up to equivalence!) the following category:

- An object consists of the following data:

  - An object $X^i$ in each $\mathcal{C}^i$.
  - An isomorphism $d^j X^i \cong X^{i+1}$ for each $i$ and $j$, such that for all $j$ and $k$, the composite
    $$\require{AMScd}
    \begin{CD}
    d^k d^j X^0 
    @>{d^k (\cong)}>>
    d^k X^1 @>{\cong}>> X^2
    \end{CD}$$
    depends only on the composite $d^k d^j$ in the simplex category $\mathbf{\Delta}$.
    So, for example, because $d^2 d^0 = d^0 d^1$ in $\mathbf{\Delta}$, the following diagram in $\mathcal{C}^2$ commutes:
    $$\begin{CD}
    d^0 d^1 X^0 @>{d^0 (\cong)}>> d^0 X^1 @>{\cong}>> X^2 \\
    @| && @| \\
    d^2 d^0 X^0 @>>{d^2 (\cong)}>  d^2 X^1 @>>{\cong}> X^2
    \end{CD}$$
- A morphism consists of a morphism in each $\mathcal{C}^i$, compatible with the structural isomorphisms in the obvious way.
- Composition and identities are inherited from each $\mathcal{C}^i$.

Manipulating the structural isomorphisms and eliminating the objects $X^1$ and $X^2$ gives us an isomorphism $d^1 X^0 \cong d^0 X^0$ in $\mathcal{C}^1$ and the following commutative diagram in $\mathcal{C}^2$:
$$\begin{CD}
d^2 d^1 X^0 @= d^1 d^1 X^0 @>{d^1 (\cong)}>> d^1 d^0 X^0 \\
@V{d^2 (\cong)}VV && @| \\
d^2 d^0 X^0 @= d^0 d^1 X^0 @>>{d^0 (\cong)}> d^0 d^0 X^0
\end{CD}$$
The isomorphism $d^1 X^0 \cong d^0 X^0$ in $\mathcal{C}^1$ can be thought of as the groupoid action on $X^0$, and the commutative diagram in $\mathcal{C}^2$ can be thought of as the compatibility between the groupoid action on $X^0$ and composition in the groupoid itself.

If this still seems vague, then take the case where we have a groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{C}^i = \textbf{Set}^{G_i}$, where $G_0$ is the set of objects of $\mathcal{G}$, $G_1$ is the set of morphisms of $\mathcal{G}$, and $G_2$ is the set of composable pairs of morphisms of $\mathcal{G}$, and each of the functors $d^j : \mathcal{C}^i \to \mathcal{C}^{i+1}$ are defined by reindexing families of sets in the following way:

- $d^0 : \mathcal{C}^0 \to \mathcal{C}^1$ sends each $G_0$-indexed family of sets to the $G_1$-indexed family where the $g$-th component is the component  of the original family at the codomain of $g$.
- $d^1 : \mathcal{C}^0 \to \mathcal{C}^1$ is defined similarly, except for using the domain of $g$ instead of the codomain of $g$.
- $d^0 : \mathcal{C}^1 \to \mathcal{C}^2$ sends each $G_1$-indexed family of sets to the $G_2$-indexed family where the $(h, g)$-th component is the $h$-th component of the original family.
- $d^1 : \mathcal{C}^1 \to \mathcal{C}^2$ sends each $G_1$-indexed family of sets to the $G_2$-indexed family where the $(h, g)$-th component is the $h \circ g$-th component of the original family.
- $d^2 : \mathcal{C}^1 \to \mathcal{C}^2$ sends each $G_1$-indexed family of sets to the $G_2$-indexed family where the $(h, g)$-th component is the $g$-th component of the original family.

It is straightforward, if extremely tedious, to verify that the limit category is equivalent to $[\mathcal{G}, \textbf{Set}]$.
The definition of an action of a localic/topological groupoid is based on this observation, replacing $\textbf{Set}^{G_i}$ with $\textbf{Sh} (G_i)$.

I do not think there is an abstract nonsense argument to get back from the "elementary" formulation to the colimit formulation.
*If* the colimit of the diagram of Grothendieck toposes exists then its underlying category must be the limit, but a priori we do not even know that the limit category is a Grothendieck topos, let alone one that has the required universal property.
So the colimit formulation is stronger in some sense.